# C# microsoft.office.interop.excel Add Chart

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a table filtered like below.
[image]
And I add the chart beside by C# with microsoft.office.interop.excel.

But when I cancel the filter,the chart may be distorted.

[image]
How to solve it then?

Comment: Before you posted this question with the title _"C# microsoft.office.interop.excel Add Chart"_, you would have been prompted with _"Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person"_.  Do you think your title meets that criteria?

Comment: _"But when I cancel the filter"_ - what filter?  Why does the 2nd image have considerably more data rows?  Why is the **date** column truncated?  Makes it hard for us to determine the correct data series and compare it to the graph

Comment: @MickyD The information you want has nothing  to do with the matter, so I just simplify it. Thanks All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this setting on your chart ...

[image: Format Chart Area]

... you can do this programmatically using this property on your `ChartObject` instance ...

```
chartObject.Placement = XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating;
```

These are the other options so it fits the bill.  I tested it and it works ...

[image: Options]